# How to get all the site feeds from alfresco site?

Tags: java, alfresco, cmis, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-maven

1.Below lines of codes returning max 30 feeds only

```
siteFeeds = activityService.getSiteFeedEntries("testSite");
```

2.Below lines of codes returning max 30 feeds only.

```
List<ActivityFeedEntity> activityFeedEntities = activityFeedDAO.selectSiteFeedEntries("testSite", 1000);
```

3. I thought to get all feeds per user and then tried with "admin" but here also i am nont able to get more than 30 feeds

   `int skipCount = 0;
   for(int i =0; i <10; i++) {
       PagingRequest pagingRequest = new PagingRequest(skipCount, 15);
       PagingResults<ActivityFeedEntity> activityFeedEntities = activityFeedDAO.selectPagedUserFeedEntries("admin", null, "testSite", false, false, i, pagingRequest);
       skipCount = skipCount + 15;
   }`

following are the values set in repository.properties

```
# Feed max ID range to limit maximum number of entries
activities.feed.max.idRange=1000000
# Feed max size (number of entries)
activities.feed.max.size=200
# Feed max age (eg. 44640 mins => 31 days)
activities.feed.max.ageMins=44640
```

Could anyone please help me how can i get all site feeds for a particular alfresco site

Comment: Any help or insight  would be highly appreciated

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you used? Are you sure that there more then 30 feed?
Pls use this sql to make sure that there more then 30 feeds

`select id as id, activity_type as activityType, activity_summary as activitySummary, post_user_id as postUserId, site_network as siteNetwork, post_date as postDate  
      from alf_activity_feed  
      where feed_user_id = #{nullValue}  
      and site_network = #{siteNetwork}  
      order by post_date desc`

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, i uploaded 50 files, download 15 files, deleted 10 files and previewed 15 files, that is why i am expecting number of feeds should be greater than 30.

Could you please help me to know if there is any alfresco api so that i can fire this query from java code.

Comment: I have alfresco-repository-5.1.e.jar in maven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested with this scenarion sdk2 and it is giving me more than 30 entry.

```
List<ActivityFeedEntity> feeds= activityFeedDAO.selectSiteFeedEntries("demo", 100);
System.out.println(feeds.size());
```